# Show that $p+q^{2}=1$ where $x^{3}+px+q=0$ and one of the roots is the reciprocal of the other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

let the three roots be $z, 1/z, t$.

So $z+1/z+t=0$ and $zt+1+t/z=p$ and $z(1/z)t=-q=t$

$-1/z-z=t$

$p+q^{2}=zt+1+t/z + t^{2}$

How do I simplify the RHS to get 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$-1/z-z=t \Rightarrow t/z + tz = -t^2$.

$p+q^{2}=zt+1+t/z + t^{2} = 1 - t^2 + t^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$zt+t/z =t(z+1/z) = - t^2{}{}{}$.